# Pandoc beamer conversion from markdown shows error producing PDF

Tags: latex, pandoc, beamer

I am using the example 8 in the demo website, https://pandoc.org/demos.html

```
`pandoc -t beamer SLIDES -o example8.pdf`
```

First, I have to add .md file extension to the SLIDES otherwise, pandoc complains. This is not the main problem, but the example doesn't work as it is.

```
`pandoc -t beamer SLIDES.md -o example8.pdf`
```

gives me the following error(main problem) message.

```
`Error producing PDF.
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\beamer@firstminutepatches \endgroup 
                                             \AtBeginDocument {\@ifundef...
l.96 \begin{document}`
```

Funny enough (after hitting enter), i get pdf output. My environment is the following.

pandoc 2.17.1.1, pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)

Comment: The example works fine for me. Can you show your latex .log file?

Comment: i tried to paste the log here but it complains it's too long. is there a way to attach a file? (sorry i am newbie here)

Comment: If it is too long to edit it into the question, you could share it via pastebin.com or https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Here is the link to the .log file. https://pastebin.com/dZftBVRu

Comment: You have an ancient beamer version installed in `/home/wontak/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/` This does not mix well with a newer kernel

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ancient beamer package version.
I haven't thought that because my texlive version was fairly new(2022) as I have upgraded the entire system recently. 
Since tlmgr was complaining about local version is older than repository I had to issue 
`tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2022/tlnet-final` to update beamer `tlmgr install` and everything is back on track.